# ngix shows 404 for php files in same directory

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404

I have nodejs and react app in different folders. I need a php folder too but when i create a folder with php files in it. If i go to

```
https://mywebsite/rcon/index.php
```

shows 404 for them. Almost searching for a fix for 24 hours but cant fix it. Here my nginx default file.

```
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log;
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server { listen 443 ssl;
server_name mywebsite;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/staff/;
    try_files $uri /index.html index /rcon/index.php /rcon/ index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    # With php-fpm (or other unixsockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    # fastcgi_pass127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
 location /api {
        proxy_pass http://myip:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
location /fivem {
    proxy_pass http://myip:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
   # Increase http2 max sizes
   http2_max_field_size 64k;
   http2_max_header_size 64k;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `root` statement for the `location ~ \.php$` block. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block).

Comment: I added root /home/ubuntu/rcon/; but still the same after restart nginx

Comment: That appears to be the incorrect value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root), but you probably want to use `root  /home/ubuntu;`

Comment: Yay its fixed. Thank for help !